# compiling a .pro file using qt-creator with dependencies?

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm a total C++ beginner. 
I'd like to compile [this repository](https://github.com/thegedge/StereoReconstruction). I have qt-creator and all dependencies installed on my machine as outlined in `README.md`, although they may be newer versions in certain cases.

I'm unclear how to tell qt-creator where to find these dependencies? When I attempt to make `StereoReconstruction.pro` I get error messages related to an inability to find the dependencies.

I'd very much appreciate a boost on this. Any advice is appreciated !

Comment: You have to write an little `Makefile`, `qt-creator` creates a big `Makefile`, Each role is a dependency in `Makefile`. I prefer to you learn how to write `Makefile`. http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

Comment: On which platform? Please post the error message as well...

Comment: ubuntu 16.04; I'm not on that machine now, but the error message is simply stating that the dependencies (which are installed on the machine) are not located when required by the compilation

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to avoid adding local machine-specific paths to source files of a community project. For Qt projects, add them in the **additional arguments** section of qmake settings in project build steps:
[image: Qt local project settings]
for include path, add `INCLUDEPATH+=/path/to/include/dir`, and for library path, add `LIBS+=-L/path/to/library/dir`